# Unity2D: How to resume timer even after application has quit

Tags: c#

basically I have a countdown timer with in my game. What I basically want to do is continue my timer playing even if I close out of my application and play it again, I want the timer to continue counting down. Kind of like clash of clan when the counter is still work when the app is closed. For example: if I exit the game and the timer is on 1:30 (1 minute, 30 seconds). Then if I restart the game 30 seconds later, the timer should show 1:00 (1 minute, 0 seconds) Or if I close the game 30 seconds later, the timer should show 1:00 (1 minute, 0 seconds)

So far this is as far as I've got:

public class TimeManager: MonoBehaviour {

```
public Text timer;
float minutes = 5;
float seconds = 0;
float miliseconds = 0;
public int curHealth;
public int maxHealth = 3;

void Start ()
{
    curHealth = maxHealth;
}

void Awake ()
{

    if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey("TimeOnExit"))
    { 
        var x = DateTime.Now - DateTime.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("TimeOnExit"));
        PlayerPrefs.DeleteKey("TimeOnExit");
    }

}
void Update(){
    if(miliseconds <= 0){
        if(seconds <= 0){
            minutes--;
            seconds = 59;
        }
        else if(seconds >= 0){
            seconds--;
        }

        miliseconds = 100;
    }

    miliseconds -= Time.deltaTime * 100;

    //Debug.Log(string.Format("{0}:{1}:{2}", minutes, seconds, (int)miliseconds));
    timer.text = string.Format("{0}:{1}", minutes, seconds, (int)miliseconds);
}
private void OnApplicationQuit()
{
    PlayerPrefs.SetString("TimeOnExit", DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString());
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TimeOnExit is good but you also need to store either the *target* time or *remaining* time of each countdown timer (in case you have more than one - e.g., multiple Woodcutters producing Wood).

Then, in the startup code for the game, you need to run through your game loop once per second that the user was absent.  If a timer would have triggered an event, you trigger that event in this loop (Woodcutter adds 1 Wood to Barn).

If you've ever seen a game with a progress bar at startup, there's a good chance that's part of what's going on.

Depending on your game and how long the user was gone, you might need to simulate multiple iterations of the same timer (Woodcutter adds 1 Wood to Barn and then starts working on the next Wood - over and over until the time is caught up).

Finally, you would need to re-instantiate the actual timers that existed and need to continue during live play.  Be sure to figure out where they are within the 5-minute loop.  If all of the timers are off by a few seconds, nobody will notice but if a restart means they all line up, that will seem strange.

Once you get sophisticated, there are techniques that are faster than a second-by-second (or whatever time period makes sense for your game) simulation of the time that went by but that's a good place to start.

Here's a hint:  If you store an array of the target times and what event should trigger, it could be easy enough to cycle through the ones that are in the past and trigger them in order.  Be sure to insert new target times into the array for repeating events.

Good Luck!